# Sed command doesnt fully parse input file

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a `5.1GB` file which is one line of text with no line breaks.

I have been provided with the following command to append a new line character after every `{...}`:

`'s/{[^}]*}/&\n/g' input > output.txt`

This works as intended, however it doesn't fully complete, it doesn't throw an error messages to the console either.

The reason it doesn't complete is because `output.txt` is always `1.1GB` so I am missing `~3.9GB` of data.

I have also tried to do an inline `sed -i 's/{[^}]*}/&\n/g' input` which also produces a `1.1GB` file.

Is `sed` limited to a specific output size? I couldn't find a similar use case.

In addition I tried using `tr` which did produce the full output size but it seems you cannot replace 1 character with multiple with the `tr` command. This didn't work:

`tr '}' '}\n' < input > output.txt`

Is there a way to make sed complete the file fully?

Comment: Could it be there is an EOF character (0x04 or Ctrl-D) hiding in your input file? That might make sed terminate prematurely.

Comment: Most `sed` implementations don't have a line length limitation, but `sed` needs to malloc enough memory to process it. You may be hitting a limit on the memory available. `Perl` usually doesn't have this problem, if you don't want to use `perl` you can split the input into smaller files, process via sed and combine them at the end.

Comment: You don't have to match a whole block, just the trailing `}`: `s/}/}\n'/g`. (Demoting my previous answer to this comment because it didn't fix the actual problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Perl?

```
perl -e '$/ = "}"; print "$_\n" while <>' input > output.txt
```

- `$/` is the input record separator.
- `<>` is the diamond operator - it reads blocks delimited by `$/` from the input file.
- `$_` is the topic variable, populated by `while <>`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, just to help me and maybe others who haven't used perl, how does that work? I assume `$_` is the last match and `<>` is not empty? what about `$\ =` is that current character?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards: Updated.

Answer (score 0):

try maybe option `-u` for unbuffered

```
sed -u 's/{[^}]*}/&\n/g' input > output.txt
```

an also

```
sed -u 's/{[^}]*}/&\n/;P;D' input > output.txt
```